# отобразить массив в виде упорядоченного списка на html-странице

Tags: javascript

Суть заключается в том что, есть у нас список (масив) const fruits = ["lemon","apple","orange","banana"];В виде упорядочного списка при том если в етом масиве будет Apple то до него нужно добавить какой нибуть слово:
1.lemon
2.green apple
3.orange
4.banana

Немного накодил не могу понять что дальше делать,подскажите что не так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нормально код вставить можно*?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruits = ["lemon", "apple", "orange", "banana"];

let items = '';

fruits.forEach((el) => {
  el === 'apple' ? items += `<li>green ${el}</li>` : items += `<li>${el}</li>`;
});

const list = document.createElement('ol');
list.innerHTML = items;
document.body.appendChild(list);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const list2 = document.createElement('ol');

fruits.forEach((el) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  el === 'apple' ? li.textContent = `green ${el}` : li.textContent = el;
  list2.appendChild(li);
});

document.body.appendChild(list2);
```